# Dynamic expandable datatable with multiple mysql tables?

Tags: php, codeigniter, join, dynamic, datatables

I am working on dynamic j query data table where i want to show data from 3 tables.
It should be expandable.I am done to achieve with 1 table. but after joins another 2 tables its not working.
I am attaching my tables format and all pictures how should be my data look.

I have total 4 tables. employee_master,uk_slip,germany_slip,poland_slip.
each user have his pay_slips for each country for each month.
For eg. XYZ is employee.
he will get his 3 salary_slips for 2018-FEBRUARY.I want to show one datatable where first user will see his name then on expand datatable he will get in below format his all slips. 
[image]
My current code is is showing only data from uk_slip. after `UK` another tables data should be display.

My model:

```
public function get_all_payslips()
    {
        $empid = $this->session->userdata('EMPLOYEE_ID');
        $orgid = $this->session->userdata('CURRENT_ORG_ID');                    
        $where = "EMPLOYEE_ID ='".$empid."' ";
        $response = array();
        $queryString = "SELECT
                         em.EMPLOYEE_ID,
                         em.EMPLOYEE_NAME
                        FROM                                   
                        uk_slip assd,
                        employee_master em
                        WHERE
                        em.".$where."
                        GROUP BY em.EMPLOYEE_ID
                        order by em.EMPLOYEE_NAME asc";                            
        $query = $this->db->query($queryString);

        foreach ($query->result() as $data) 
        {         
            $result = array();
            $result['EMPLOYEE_NAME'] = $data-> EMPLOYEE_NAME;
            $queryString = "SELECT
                        mo.months,
                        MONTH((assd.pay_period)) as monthss,
                        YEAR((assd.pay_period)) as PAY_YEAR,
                        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(assd.id)) as action,
                        CONCAT(assd.ORG_ID,',',germany.ORG_ID,',',poland.ORG_ID) as org 
                        FROM                         
                        uk_new_salary_slip assd,
                        employee_master em,                               
                        months mo,
                        germany_slip germany,
                        poland_slip poland
                        WHERE
                        assd.emp_id = ". $data->EMPLOYEE_ID ."
                          AND mo.id =  MONTH((assd.pay_period))
                          GROUP BY monthss,PAY_YEAR
                          order by PAY_YEAR desc";

            $query1 = $this->db->query($queryString);                       
            $children = array();
            foreach ($query1->result() as $data1)
                {
                    $yearArray = array();                          
                    $yearArray['month'] = $data1->months;
                    $yearArray['year'] = $data1->PAY_YEAR;
                    $yearArray['org'] = $data1->org;                            
                    $yearArray['action'] = $data1->action;
                    array_push($children, $yearArray);
                }
                $result['children'] = $children;
                array_push($response, $result);

        }                   
        return $response;                   
    }
```

My View with jquery datatable:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
        { 
        var table = null;
        $.ajax({
          url:"<?php echo base_url('responsible/get_all_payslips'); ?>",
          datatype:'json',            
              success: function(response)
                {
                  var response1 = $.parseJSON(response);
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(response1['pay_slips']));
                  var data = response1['pay_slips'];
                  table = $('.datatables').DataTable({                 
                  columns : [
                      {
                        className      : 'details-control',
                        defaultContent : '',
                        data           : null,
                        orderable      : false
                      },
                      {data : 'EMPLOYEE_NAME'},

                    ],                  
                    data : data,                  
                    pagingType : 'full_numbers',
                  });
                }
      });

    function format(data) 
        {
            return '<div class="details-container">'+
              '<table  class="details-table table-bordered">'+
                '<thead>'+
                      '<tr>'+                  
                        '<th>Year</th>'+
                        '<th>Month</th>'+
                        '<th>PDF</th>'+               
                      '</tr>'+
                    '</thead>'+
                    '<tbody>'+
                      '<tr>'+
                      '<td>'+data.PAY_YEAR+'</td>'+
                      '<td>'+data.monthss+'</td>'+
                      '<td>'+'<a class="btn btn-success" href="data.action">'+data.action+'</a>'+'</td>'+
                      '</tr>'+
                      '<tr>'+
                      '<td>'+data.PAY_YEAR+'</td>'+
                      '<td>'+data.monthss+'</td>'+
                      '<td>'+'<a class="btn btn-success" href="data.action">'+data.action+'</a>'+'</td>'+
                      '</tr>'+
                    +'</tbody>'+
                  '</table>'+
                  '</div>';    
        };
        $('.datatables tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () 
            {
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var row = table.row( tr );
                console.log(row.data()['children']);
                var childrenArray = row.data()['children'];
                var check = '<div class="details-container">'+
                '<table  class="details-table table-bordered">'+
                  '<thead>'+
                        '<tr>'+                  
                          '<th>Year</th>'+
                          '<th>Month</th>'+
                          '<th>PDF</th>'+               
                        '</tr>'+
                      '</thead>'+
                      '<tbody>';
                      for(var i=0;i<childrenArray.length;i++)
                        {
                            check +='<tr>'+
                            '<td>'+childrenArray[i].year+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+childrenArray[i].month+'</td>';
                            var orgid = childrenArray[i].org.split(",");
                            var action = childrenArray[i].action.split(",");
                            var obj = {};                    
                            for (var k = 0; k < orgid.length; k++) 
                            {
                                obj[orgid[k]] = action[k];
                            }
                            var arrayData = sortObject(action);
                            check +='<td>';     

                            for(var j=0;j<arrayData.length;j++)
                                {
                                    var country = "";
                                    var color = "";
                                    if(arrayData[j].key=="40")
                                        {
                                           country = "1";
                                           color = "INDIANRED";
                                        }
                                    else if(arrayData[j].key=="41")
                                        {
                                           country = "2";
                                           color = "LIGHTPINK";
                                        }
                                    else  if(arrayData[j].key=="47")
                                        {
                                           country = "3";
                                           color = "LIGHTSALMON";
                                        }
                                    else
                                        {
                                           country = "UK";
                                           color = "DARKKHAKI";
                                        }
                                       check+='<a class="btn btn-success"  style="background-color : ' + color  + ';" href="<?php echo base_url()?>responsible/uk_pdf/'+arrayData[j].value+'">'+country+
                                                        '</a>|';
                                }
                              check +='</td></tr>';

                        }


                    check += '</tbody>'+
                            '</table>'+
                            '</div>';



                    if (row.child.isShown()) 
                        {
                           tr.next('tr').removeClass('details-row');
                           row.child.hide();
                           tr.removeClass('shown');
                        }
                    else 
                        {
                           row.child(check).show();
                           tr.next('tr').addClass('details-row');
                           tr.addClass('shown');
                        }
            });

    });

    function sortObject(obj) 
        {
            var arr = [];
            console.log(arr);
            for (var prop in obj) 
                {
                    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) 
                        {
                            arr.push({
                                'key': prop,
                                'value': obj[prop]
                            });
                        }
                }
            arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a.value - b.value; });

            return arr;
        }
```

In all 3 slip_tables `emp_id` is common. then in each table having ORG_ID column. for UK having ORG_ID = 40, for GERMANY = 57, for POLAND = 47.  In uk_slip having column `pay_period` for getting `MONTH and YEAR` with mysql functions `MONTH` and `YEAR`. and in germany and poland having `pay_from` to get the same.

Comment: I think your query is bad but I cannot tell because you have not provided the table definitions. Can you do that and explain how the tables are related.

Comment: in all slips table `emp_id` is common. from uk_slip `pay_period` and from rest 2 tables `pay_from` column is used for getting YEAR and MONTH with mysql function month and year. in all 3 tables ORG_ID is common. for uk_slip = 40, germany_slip= 47, poland_slip=41.

Comment: Add it to the question. Don't post that in a comment.

Comment: `print_r()` after each query to make sure the result is as you expect.